# IS PCA redundant when the first PC equals the mean of the data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, dataset, computational-statistics

I have a situation where the principle component of my data is almost equal to the mean of the data. Does this make PCA redundant? Does PCA not work in this setting?

Comment: you need to center and scale your data before applying PCA, as I discuss here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385775/normalizing-vs-scaling-before-pca/385782#385782

Comment: what does that mean "principle component is equal to the mean of the data"? PC is a variable and an axis (dimension). Mean, the centroid, is a point with its coordinates. Perhaps you wanted to say "the first PC of the raw (uncenteted) data comes through the centroid"?